# MySQL rating/ladder system

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

*tbl_MATCHES*

```
id
contestant_1
contestant_2
winner
```

*tbl_CONTESTANTS*

```
id
name
```

The goal is to get each contestant's win percentage. That is, count how many matches each contestant won, and divide that by the total number of matches each contestant took part in. This is currently working, but it seems cumbersome:

```
SELECT all_matches.contestant_id, num_matches, num_wins, 
    (num_wins / num_matches * 100.0) AS win_percent FROM ( 

        // get total number of wins for each contestant

        SELECT contestants.id AS contestant_id, 
        COUNT(matches.winner) AS num_wins 
        FROM contestants 
        LEFT JOIN matches 
        ON matches.winner = contestants.id 
        GROUP BY matches.winner 
    ) all_matches 

    // join total number of wins to total number of matches played

    JOIN ( 
        SELECT contestant_id, COUNT(contestant_id) AS num_matches FROM ( 

            // get list of all matches played by all contestants

            SELECT contestants.id AS contestant_id 
            FROM matches 
            JOIN contestants ON contestants.id = matches.contestant_1 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT contestants.id AS contestant_id 
            FROM matches 
            JOIN contestants ON contestants.id = matches.contestant_2 
        ) all_m 
        GROUP BY contestant_id 
    ) all_matches 
    ON all_matches.contestant_id = all_matches.contestant_id 
    ORDER BY win_percent DESC
```

I feel like this sort of thing must have been done before, and I'm looking for some help optimizing this or a link to a better one someone has already done

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: -1: No explain plan, no create table statements, no index details, (and to a lesser extent, no explanation for denormalized schema design, no reason for selecting every single contestant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this approach:

```
SELECT 
    contestants.id AS contestant_id,
    COUNT(*) AS num_matches,
    SUM( CASE WHEN matches.winner = contestants.id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
        AS num_wins,
    SUM( CASE WHEN matches.winner = contestants.id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
        / COUNT(*) * 100 AS win_percent 
FROM matches 
JOIN contestants 
ON contestants.id IN( matches.contestant_1, matches.contestant_2 ) 
GROUP BY contestants.id
```

Comment: Nice thats perfect. Thank you!